# User double quote in batch script if statement

Tags: shell, scripting, batch-file

It seems someone suggests to use double quote in windows batch script if statement like:

```
IF "%FLAG%"=="1" (do something)
```

However, in my case I found that with using double quote may cause the script fails at the comparison. Can anyone see what could be wrong here?

PS: I've `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` in the script.

EDIT:
This statement even fails when ECHO %FLAG% is 1.

EDIT2:
This is my script.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set CFG=C:\config
set LOBBYLIST=%CFG%\serverlist_lobby_server.txt
set DBDAEMONLIST=%CFG%\serverlist_daemon_server.txt
set LIST=
set FOLDER=

set /p OP=   Delete 1.Lobby, 2.dbdaemon, All? (1,2,a) 

:BEGIN
if %OP%==1 (GOTO DELETE_LOBBY_DUMP)
if %OP%==2 (GOTO DELETE_DBDAEMON_DUMP)
GOTO END


:DELETE_LOBBY_DUMP
set LIST=%LOBBYLIST%
set FOLDER=LobbyServer
GOTO START_DELETE
:DELETE_DBDAEMON_DUMP
set LIST=%DBDAEMONLIST%
set FOLDER=DBDaemonServer\Lobby
GOTO START_DELETE
:DELETE_ALL
set /a OP = OP + 1
GOTO BEGIN




:START_DELETE
for %%b in (%LIST%) do ( 
    echo %%b
    for /f %%a in (%%b) do ( 
        echo    %%a
        dir \\%%a\c$\Services\%FOLDER%\*.dmp | find "dmp"
        dir \\%%a\c$\WINDOWS\PCHEALTH\ERRORREP\UserDumps\*.hdmp | find "hdmp"
    ))

echo.
echo.

if %isAll%==1 (set isContinue=y
) ELSE (set /p isContinue=   Continue? (y/n)
)

if %isContinue%==y (
    for %%b in (%LIST%) do ( 
        echo %%b
        for /f %%a in (%%b) do ( 
            echo    %%a
            del \\%%a\c$\Services\%FOLDER%\*.dmp
            del \\%%a\c$\WINDOWS\PCHEALTH\ERRORREP\UserDumps\*.hdmp
        )
    )
)

if %isAll%==1 (GOTO DELETE_ALL)

GOTO END
:END

pause
```

Comment: In what way is it failing? And which line (you generically refer to "`%FLAG%`" yet that variable doesn't appear in your script).

Comment: @Dennis: %isAll%==1 will work, while "%isAll%"=="1" won't. Sorry for the confusing.

Comment: In what way does it not work (it works for me)?

Answer (score 0):

Delayed expansion has nothing to do with it.

What is the value of `%FLAG%` when the comparison fails, i.e. what does `ECHO %FLAG%` output?

Comment: This statement even fails when ECHO %FLAG% is 1.

Comment: @Stan: then something else is wrong. Post your script (or a relevant snippet), because this should always work.